# Richfaces tabPanel - using the same page for the different tabs changing the content dynamically

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam

I am using Seam 2.1.2 and RichFaces 3.3.2.SR1.

```
<a4j:form>
    <rich:tabPanel switchType="ajax">
        <rich:tab label="TAB 1" actionListener="#{outControl.tab1}" immediate="true">
            <ui:include src="/pages/agenda/TabContain.xhtml" />
        </rich:tab>
        <rich:tab label="TAB 2" actionListener="#{outControl.tab2}">
            <ui:include src="/pages/agenda/TabContain.xhtml" />
        </rich:tab>
        ...
```

TabContain.xhtml:

```
<rich:extendedDataTable value="#{manBean.seDataModel}" var="out" id="bc_table" 
    sortMode="#{manBean.sortMode}" selectionMode="#{manBean.selectionMode}" 
    tableState="#{manBean.tableState}" selection="#{manBean.selection}" 
    rowKeyVar="rkvar">
    <rich:column sortable="false" id="bc_col_0">
        ...
```

The content of `extendedDataTable` should be dependent of the tab selected. My first approach was to set an `actionListener` in the tabs and change the `manBean` within that action. After that `actionListener` even if I can see in the logs that the `manBean` has changed, this is not reflected in the page in the browser. It's like not refreshing. I tried setting a `rerender` in the `rich:tab` but that's also not doing it.

Any idea? Also happy about other approaches, this might be not the best one.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I can put this into words easily but here it goes...
If you have a fixed number of tabs and you know the possible values ahead of time, consider passing a parameter to the reusable template via ui:param.

Example
Template with the tabpanel

```
<rich:tabPanel switchType="ajax">
  <rich:tab label="TAB 1" >
      <ui:include src="/pages/agenda/TabContain.xhtml">
         <ui:param name="dataModel" value="#{dataBean.dataset1}" />
      </ui:include>
  </rich:tab>
  <rich:tab label="TAB 2">
     <ui:include src="/pages/agenda/TabContain.xhtml">
       <ui:param name="dataModel" value="#{dataBean.dataset2}" />
     </ui:include>
  </rich:tab>
```

Then in the resusableDataTable template

```
<rich:extendedDataTable value="#{dataModel}" ....>
    <rich:column sortable="false" id="bc_col_0">
....
</rich:extendedDataTable>
```

The value of "dataModel" will then be passed into TabContain.xhtml as a parameter, and replaced anywhere there is a #{dataModel}.

Hope this helps, I'm doing essentially this in our project.

Answer (score 1):

ok, the approach above worked out after a couple of tries using actionListener (I was not changing the correct attribute).

```
actionListener
```

1- it fires when the tab is selected
2- it grabs the managed bean through:

```
ManBean mb = (ManBean) context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("manBean");
```

3- it modifies the managed bean which is the `value` in the `extendedDataTable`

4- `important!:` add a `f:subview` around each -`ui:include`- to avoid a "duplicate component ID" error!

Would you say there is a better approach for this?

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like the approach I'd take. You could merge your server-side code samples into Rich Taylor's answer above.